# How to add to list of child object in Thymeleaf/Spring Boot post request

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm looking for a solution to manage a **one-to-many** relation within a *Thymeleaf* form. I'm running *Spring Boot* and *Hibernate*.

I want to post a value of my child object which is of type address while submitting the information of the user and I don't know how to bind it in thymeleaf. I should also remind that in current form I just want to add a single value of address when submitting a user form. I'm looking to do something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{addresses[].address.addressDesc}" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" /> 
        <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('addresses')}" th:errors="*{addresses}" class="validation-message"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

My User entity:

```
...

/** Field to store username */
@Column(name = "username", nullable = false, length = 45)
@NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your name")
private String username;

/** Many to many relationship with address via user_address */
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_address", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_id"))
private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>(0);

...
```

My Address Entity:

```
public class Address implements java.io.Serializable {

    /** Primary key address id */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "address_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer addressId;

    /** Field to store actual address */
    @Column(name = "address_desc", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String addressDesc;

    /** From Date for which the address was in use */
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "from_date", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private Date fromDate;

    /** Field to store the date till address was in use */
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "to_date", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private Date toDate;

    /** user_address entity mapping */
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "address")
    private Set<UserAddress> userAddresses = new HashSet<UserAddress>(0);

    ...

}
```

Is there a way I can bind it to a single text field?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a nice way to do this while `addresses` is a `Set`, because there's no way to refer to a specific item within that `Set`. If you can use a `List` instead (or add an extra getter/setter to User which converts between Set and List) then it's just a case of setting `th:field` on the input correctly.

The `th:field` attribute first needs to reference the first item in the List using the array notation `addresses[0]`, and then you're using `addressDesc` within that address:

```
th:field="*{addresses[0].addressDesc}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `th:field` like this:

```
<div th:each="address, iterstat: ${user.addresses}">
    <input th:field="*{addresses[__${iterstat.index}__].addressDesc}"/>
</div>
```